# Post photo on Facebook group using graph api error(#120) Invalid album id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

someone please help me. i'm trying to post a picture to the group but it's not working. Posts still appear on the group but no photos.
My code

```
$post_data = array(
    'caption' => $mess,
    'url' => $urlphoto
    );
try {
 $response = $fb->post('/944379269276566/photos', $post_data, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this error occurs when you include a question mark (?) in the caption.
and this is a Facebook bug
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/739380653703276/